# Magento on cPanel

Tags: javascript, php, magento, svn, filezilla

I am using cPanel for Magento. Now because I cannot use SVN because I don't have full access to server. I've always to upload the modifications through FTP and I am using Filezila. It's getting harder now because I always have to find the modified files and upload and replace.

Is there anyway I can automatically find which files are modified and upload like it happens in case of SVN commits?

Or any other system?

Comment: have you seen http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/5157

Comment: if you use a decent IDE such as netbeans this can sync updated files for you via FTP.